# syntax error : missing ')' before ';'

Tags: c, visual-c++

Errors are like this:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'

error C2143: syntax error : missing ']' before ')'

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'

error C2059: syntax error : ')'

error C2059: syntax error : ']'
```

The program is like this

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef int NodeType;
#define MAXVEX 100;

typedef struct EdgeNode
{
    NodeType tailvex;//弧起点在顶点表的下标
    NodeType headvex;//弧终点在顶点表的下标
    struct EdgeNode* headlink;//入边表指针域，指向终点相同的下一条边
    struct EdgeNode* taillink;//出边表指针域，指向起点相同的下一条边
}EdgeNode;

typedef struct VertexNode
{
    NodeType data;
    EdgeNode* firstin;  //指向该顶点的入边表中的第一个顶点
    EdgeNode* firstout; //指向该顶点的出边表的第一个顶点
}VertexNode,VerNodeList[MAXVEX];
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**

Why can this happen? Before asking the question,I doubted the reason of misuse of `typedef` so I checked  validation of `typedef`. But it appears  there is no apparent error. So what is the reason?

Answer (score 11):

```
#define MAXVEX 100;
```

Remove the semicolon, it should be

```
#define MAXVEX 100
```